# Split at first and last occurrence of a character?

Tags: python

I have a list of strings as such (amount, address, payment):

```
"44.53 54 orchard rd Cash"
"32.34 600 sprout brook lane Card"
```

I am just trying to get the address from each string. It seems to me the best way to go about this would be to split at the first and last occurrence of a space. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Python `split` function is defined like this: [`str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Similarly, there is[`str.rsplit(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit).

This means that you can split off just the beginning and the ending:

```
>>> s = "44.53 54 orchard rd Cash"
>>> s.split(maxsplit=1)
['44.53', '54 orchard rd Cash']
>>> s.rsplit(maxsplit=1)
['44.53 54 orchard rd', 'Cash']
```

Then, to simply split the string into 3, you can write a simple function:

```
>>> def purchase_parts(purchase):
...     lsplit = purchase.split(maxsplit=1)
...     rsplit = lsplit[1].rsplit(maxsplit=1)
...     return (lsplit[0], rsplit[0], rsplit[1])
... 
>>> purchase_parts("44.53 54 orchard rd Cash")
('44.53', '54 orchard rd', 'Cash')
>>> purchase_parts("32.34 600 sprout brook lane Card")
('32.34', '600 sprout brook lane', 'Card')
```

Still, I would suggest to switch to separated value list, because then you can just split using that separator, but also directly support importing/exporting of csv format (comma separated values) files.

Manual solution:

```
>>> [p.strip() for p in "32.34, 600 sprout brook lane, Card".split(',')]
['32.34', '600 sprout brook lane', 'Card']
```

Comment: Most single-line addresses are given in a format with commas in them, in which case your manual solution would fail.

Comment: @n00dle Comma isn't a single character that can be used to separate. Also, escape your values. What I provided works for askers data, and I already suggested using csv.

Comment: "Escape your values" is a perfectly reasonable mantra, if the data you have is already escaped. My point was (and TBF, I didn't state it very clearly), I'm not sure why space delimited is any worse than comma delimited for this case. As an aside, I'd also say that your `lsplit`/`rsplit` method requires more code and is less readable than simply splitting on spaces and slicing.

Comment: @n00dle Because whitespace has no meaning unless you give one to it. CSV deals with meaningful whitespace by encasing the value in quotes... If you think about it, there's absolutely no reason to put whitespace between `"value0 "" value1    "` other than to waste space, and now you're halfway to reinventing CSV. The question is why do that? Python provides `csv` module, so you don't even need to worry about parsing it yourself. Also `csv` is a standard across python, meaning that you can plug it into a lot more places without thinking twice, unlike with homegrown formats.

Comment: That assumes you have control of the upstream stack. Quite often legacy systems are whitespace delimited and in that case, converting to CSV isn't feasible, or is only feasible with post-processing (taking the existing whitespace delimited output and reforming it as CSV). In terms of solving the problem at hand, I don't think converting to CSV has any benefits.

Comment: In terms of solving the problem at hand, nowhere has the asker mentioned any legacy systems that are impossible to maintain so I don't see the point in this.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially do something like:

```
line = "44.53 54 orchard rd Cash"
line_parts = line.split(" ")
address = " ".join(line_parts[1:-1])
```

It's a bit untidy and definitely brittle to changes in line format, but would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your method, splitting at the first and last spaces, but you need to join back the rest (in the middle):

```
def get_address(s):
    s = s.split()
    return ' '.join(s[1:-1])
    # s[1:-1] will remove the first (amount) and the last (payment) values
    # ' '.join will then put back the spaces that were removed from the address by s.split
```

Input:

```
print(get_address("44.53 54 orchard rd Cash"))
print(get_address("32.34 600 sprout brook lane Cash"))
```

Output:

```
54 orchard rd
600 sprout brook lane
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a regular expression to be a bit more flexible and robust. Here, the first two `\d+` elements say that you must at first have two digits separated by a dot, then a space, then your address as returned result (in parenthesis `()`) consisting of any characters (`\w`) or (`[]`) whitespace characters (`\W`) until a space and another sequence of characters (`\w+`).

```
import re

addresses = [
    "44.53 54 orchard rd Cash",
    "32.34 600 sprout brook lane Card"
]

addresses = [re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+ ([\w\W]+) \w+', address)[0] for address in addresses]
print(addresses)  # ['54 orchard rd', '600 sprout brook lane']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the first and last using unpacking and the reassemble then rest to form the address:

```
amount,*rest,payment = s.split()
address = " ".join(rest)
```